# why when change object scale not clicking unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onclicklistener, 2d-games

I'm new in programming and I want help.

I am following a tutorial on youtube. This is a swipe menu tutorial.
 the problem is now I am not able to click on prefabs to load different scene﻿ ,  I tried But unable to find the solution

```
public class SnapScrolling: MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)]
    [Header("Controllers")]
    public int panCount;
    [Range(0, 500)]
    public int panOffset;
    [Range(0f, 20f)]
    public float snapSpeed;
    [Range(0f, 10f)]
    public float scaleOffset;
    [Range(1f, 20f)]
    public float scaleSpeed;
    [Header("Other Objects")]
    public GameObject panPrefab;
    public ScrollRect scrollRect;

    private GameObject[] instPans;
    private Vector2[] pansPos;
    private Vector2[] pansScale;

    private RectTransform contentRect;
    private Vector2 contentVector;

    private int selectedPanID;
    private bool isScrolling;

    private void Start ()
    {
        contentRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        instPans = new GameObject[panCount];
        pansPos = new Vector2[panCount];
        pansScale = new Vector2[panCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {
            instPans[i] = Instantiate(panPrefab, transform, false);

    Button buttonCtrl = instPans[i].GetComponent<Button>();
            buttonCtrl.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => HandleClick(item.id) );


            if (i == 0) continue;
            instPans[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector2(instPans[i-1].transform.localPosition.x + panPrefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x + panOffset,
                instPans[i].transform.localPosition.y);
            pansPos[i] = -instPans[i].transform.localPosition;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (contentRect.anchoredPosition.x >= pansPos[0].x && !isScrolling || contentRect.anchoredPosition.x <= pansPos[pansPos.Length - 1].x && !isScrolling)
            scrollRect.inertia = false;
        float nearestPos = float.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {
            float distance = Mathf.Abs(contentRect.anchoredPosition.x - pansPos[i].x);
            if (distance < nearestPos)
            {
                nearestPos = distance;
                selectedPanID = i;
            }
            float scale = Mathf.Clamp(1 / (distance / panOffset) * scaleOffset, 0.5f, 1f);
            pansScale[i].x = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.x, scale + 0.3f, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            pansScale[i].y = Mathf.SmoothStep(instPans[i].transform.localScale.y, scale + 0.3f, scaleSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            instPans[i].transform.localScale = pansScale[i];
        }
        float scrollVelocity = Mathf.Abs(scrollRect.velocity.x);
        if (scrollVelocity < 400 && !isScrolling) scrollRect.inertia = false;
        if (isScrolling || scrollVelocity > 400) return;
        contentVector.x = Mathf.SmoothStep(contentRect.anchoredPosition.x, pansPos[selectedPanID].x, snapSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        contentRect.anchoredPosition = contentVector;
    }

    public void Scrolling(bool scroll)
    {
        isScrolling = scroll;
        if (scroll) scrollRect.inertia = true;
    }

    public void HandleClick(int levelId)
    {

        print ("click "+levelId);


    }

}
```

If anyone can help or advise what I should read to make it work. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add a screenshot of the Inspector of each Prefab in `instPans`. Did you test if you can click on it if it is just in the scene from beginning? Could e.g. be that you disabled `RaycastTarget` or the buttons have no collider on them ...

Comment: If you edit your question and include the link the youtube tutorial (which probably already includes screenshots and such), it would add some context that could help us answer your question.

Comment: you need `Using UnityEngine.SceneManager' then in you click you call `SceneManager.Load(0)` where zero is the number of the scene your trying to load. all scenes must be added through the build settings, click add open scene, and take note of the number of the one you wish to load. im not seeing any code here that even tries to load a scene.